# Find a series $f(r)=\sum_{0}^{\infty}a_nr^n$ s.t converges for $|r| < R$ and s.t. $\lim_{r\rightarrow R-} f(r)$ exists but series does not converge.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

Find a series $f(r)=\sum_{0}^{\infty}a_nr^n$ s.t converges for $|r| < R$ and s.t. $\lim_{r\rightarrow R-} f(r)$ exists but series does not converge.

How do I approach this? I think that $a_n r^n$ should be able to be expressed as $(k_n r)^n$  and then need to find $k_n$ such that $k_n r < 0 $ when $r < R$ so it's an alternating series of positive and negative terms and so the limit can exist as $r \rightarrow R-$ but I'm not sure how to construct this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. Try to find a simple series that sums to an expression which has an obvious limit. What is the simplest alternating series you can write down in the form you described yourself?

Don't read the rest if you want to work it out yourself.

---

Solution:

Let $f(r) = 1 - r + r^2 - r^3 + r^4 - \dots = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-r)^n$.

Then $f(r) = \frac{1}{1+r}$ for $|r|<1$, and $\lim_{r \rightarrow 1^-}f(r) = \frac{1}{2}$, but $f(1) = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - \dots$ clearly doesn't converge.